# SQL delete not working as expected

Tags: javascript, sqlite, titanium

If I put each (one at a time) in the same code the second one will update the title to var testTitle, the first does not delete the rows/items that match the WHERE.

```
function deleteTableAItem(e) {
    var db3 = Ti.Database.open('thedatabase');

    var getTheID = db3.execute('SELECT ID FROM tableA WHERE myIndexColumn=?', e.itemIndex);
    var theID = getTheID.fieldByName('ID');

    Ti.API.info(tableLinkRef + " " + theID); //they match as intended

    var testTitle = "DID I CHANGE?";

    db3.execute('DELETE FROM tableB WHERE tableLinkRef=? AND tableARef=?',theID,theTableAItemClicked); // fixed by adding another comparison.

    //db3.execute('UPDATE tableB SET titleColumn=? WHERE tableLinkRef=?',testTitle,theID); // this DOES update the titleColumn in matching rows/items when the code is active and the previous is commented out

    db3.execute('DELETE FROM tableA WHERE myIndexColumn=?', e.itemIndex); //this deletes the row from the first table. I want to delete the rows I have associated in tableB as well

    db3.close();
}
```

Comment: Is that really exactly what your code looks like? If so it won't do anything at all.

Comment: You need to show the actual code.

Comment: Stop trying to describe what you're doing, you need to **show the code**.

Comment: will do sorry. working on it.

Comment: What is the value of theTableAItemClicked?  It isn't passed into the function, so is it undefined?  Likely means that delete will never find a row to delete then.

Answer (score 1):

Your DELETE sql in the code looks fine. You may print out the entire SQL generated to see if it is really correct, or see whther sqlite is returning any error.

Comment: He's not using MySQL, he's using SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need two pieces of criteria (WHERE tableLinkRef=? AND tableARef=?',theID,theTableAItemClicked) for a DELETE and only one piece of criteria for the UPDATE (WHERE tableLinkRef=? AND tableARef=?',theID,theTableAItemClicked)

```
db3.execute('DELETE FROM tableB WHERE tableLinkRef=? AND tableARef=?',theID,theTableAItemClicked); // fixed by adding another comparison.

//db3.execute('UPDATE tableB SET titleColumn=? WHERE tableLinkRef=?',testTitle,theID); // this DOES update the titleColumn in matching rows/items when the code is active and the previous is commented out
```

Since you are saying that the update is working on the correct rows, you would just take the WHERE clause from that command.

```
db3.execute('DELETE FROM tableB WHERE tableLinkRef=?',theID);
```

It appears confusing because tableLinkRef appears to be a reference to tableA's id and tableARef seems to describe that as well.

Comment: Groups of items in tableB are linked to items in tableA all of which needs to be matched to the clicked list event. Let's say a teacher from tableA has kids from tableB seated at desk locations 1,2,3. Other teachers use desk locations  1,2,3 as well because the school uses the same list(classroom) for all classes. So I need the teacher plus the desk location. My temporary names for the variables are not great.

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the record before you update it, there is nothing to be updated.  I would just move the second line before the first, but do you really want to delete something you just spent time to update?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to update it at all, that is strictly a test to see if UPDATE worked using the arguments. THx